# pros & cons of xml.dom vs xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

I'm attempting to write an xml processor using python starting with a piece of sample code from a tutorial which uses xml.dom.minidom which provides a nice parsing method xml.dom.minidom.parse().

The documentation seems to say minidom is simpler & smaller than the full dom. Exactly what are the pros & cons of using either?

One thing I noticed is that I can't just replace importing xml.dom.minidom with xml.dom and expect the sample code to work as is. For example, xml.dom.parse() does not work giving error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'". What is the equivalent parsing method in xml.dom?

What I'm attempting to do is to traverse the tree that xml.dom.minidom.parse() gives me and look at all the attributes/objects of each node to see how the xml files I have to work with are represented in the dom tree. But something as simple as accessing the constants corresponding to .nodeType (eg ELEMENT_NODE as defined in xml.dom documentation) is giving me "not defined" errors at run-time.

If someone can point me the right way it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `xml.dom` implementation in the Python standard library. Only `minidom` is provided. Better to use `xml.etree` however.

Answer (score 1):

`xml.dom` is *not a DOM implementation*; it is merely provides access to DOM interfaces in Python terms, including a partial implementation of the [Level 3 `DomImplementationSource` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#DOMImplementationSource), through the `getDOMImplementation()` function.

The only implementation provided in the standard library is `xml.dom.minidom`.

`ELEMENT_NODE` and other constants are part of the [`Node` interface IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1950641247):

```
>>> import xml.dom
>>> xml.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE
1
```

The XML DOM is a rather.. inflexible and archaic API, designed for far less flexible programming languages. You may want to use [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) instead. There is an implementation in the standard library, or you can install [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and get additional functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Then how do I get at the constants like ELEMENT_NODE, and all the rest I might find in the xml.doc documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.dom.html)?

Comment: @rockhammer: the implementation follows the DOM Level 2 IDL, so do look at that too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will look into ElementTree. What I did find out however was that I needed to test using "if anyNode.nodeType == anyNode.ELEMENT_NODE:" instead of simply "if anyNode.nodeType == ELEMENT_NODE:". Not obvious to me why but hopefully it will dawn on me at some point.

Comment: @rockhammer: indeed, because all `Node()` *instances* implement the DOM `Node` *interface*, which includes these constants.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Martijn. I just looked into ElementTree and it does appear the opinions out there do mostly recommend ElementTree over xml.dom. I also then looked into lxml which appears to be further superior to ElementTree (ie performs faster and supports XPath which I will need down the road). The only trouble is lxml seems hard to install on a mac (10.9.2) by a novice like me as there are many moving parts (libxml2/libxslt) and some have experienced major system issues which I would hardly know how to get myself out of.

Comment: I've not had any problems installing `lxml` on Mac myself, but I do use homebrew and [`buildout.python`](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python) to manage multiple Python versions.